# How to correct this ASP.NET error

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I'm designing in my webpage. My code is a follows.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Security;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
  using System.Xml.Linq;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;

  namespace photoshops
  {
      public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

          }

          protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
              SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
              DataSet ds = new DataSet();
              string constr = null;
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
              if (IsValid != null)
              {
                  constr = @"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =librarymanagement;
                     Integrated Security=SSPI";
                  cnn.ConnectionString = constr;
                  try
                  {
                      if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                          cnn.Open();
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      string str1 = null;
                      str1 = ex.ToString();
                  }
                  cmd.Connection = cnn;
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                  cmd.CommandText = "photoset";
                  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillNo", TextBox1.Text);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", TextBox2.Text);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox3.Text);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",Rdbsdate.SelectedDate );
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", Rdbddate.SelectedDate );
                  SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numberofcopies", TextBox7.Text);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", TextBox8.Text);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", TextBox9.Text);
                  da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                  try
                  {
                      da.Fill(ds);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      string strErrMsg = ex.Message;
                      //throw new applicationException("!!!! An error an occured while
                      //inserting record."+ex.Message)
                  }
                  finally
                  {
                      da.Dispose();
                      cmd.Dispose();
                      cnn.Close();
                      cnn.Dispose();
                  }
                  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                  {
                      Msg.Text = "Photo setting sucessfullY";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Msg.Text = "photosetting failled";
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

> MY ERROR
>              image are not insert how to change in my code pls send me code
>              How to rectify.

My stored procedure,

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[photoset]
(
    @BillNo Numeric,
    @CustomerName varchar(300),
    @Address nvarchar(300),
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @Systemurl varchar,
    @Numberofcopies numeric,
    @Amount numeric,
    @Total numeric
)

AS
BEGIN
    insert into tblphotosetting
    (
      BillNo,
      CustomerName,
      Address,
      StartDate,
      EndDate,
      Systemurl,
      Numberofcopies,
      Amount,
      Total
    )
    values
    (
      @BillNo,
      @CustomerName,
      @Address,
      @StartDate,
       @EndDate,
      @Systemurl,
      @Numberofcopies,
      @Amount,
      @Total
    )
END
```

Comment: Can you show your Stored procedure ?

Comment: did you step through your code in the debugger? It looks like the code in your try catch block failed and there is no table in the dataset. Try removing your try catch temporarily and see what the exception is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another condition before the IF condtion to check if you have any tables in your dataset. This will avoid the error if the stored procedure is not returning any tables.

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{ 
   if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      Msg.Text = "Photo setting sucessfullY";
   }
   else
   {
      Msg.Text = "photosetting failled";
   }
}
```

**EDIT**  -

After seeing your stored procedure, there is only a insert statement. There is no way you will be able to fill your dataset with tables unless you write some select statement to get some result set in your stored proc.

Comment: shanbhag No record are insert how to rectify

Comment: @vimal - Are you trying to check if the records were inserted into table or not? If yes, then your current code is totally in wrong way.

Comment: Shanbhag Yes i am check but no record are insert.how to change in my code.

Comment: @vimal - you are asking for something different now which is not as part of your question. I think you better post a new question on this regard. Frame your question in such a way as to let people know that you are trying to check how to ensure if records are inserted. Post your code as well.