# Asp.net how to correct the error

Tags: asp.net

I'm designing in my web page and image are stored in my database (The project is Photostudio management system)

MY Code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace photoshops
   {
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string constr = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            if (IsValid != true )
            {
                constr = @"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog =cat; Integrated 
                                             Security=SSPI";
                cnn.ConnectionString = constr;
                try
                {
                    if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        cnn.Open();



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string str1 = null;
                    str1 = ex.ToString();
                }
                cmd.Connection = cnn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "photoset";
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillNo", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",Rdbsdate.SelectedDate );
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", Rdbddate.SelectedDate );
                SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.VarChar,  
                                  50);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numberofcopies", TextBox7.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", TextBox8.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", TextBox9.Text);
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string strErrMsg = ex.Message;
                    //throw new applicationException("!!!! An error an occured while 
                     //inserting record."+ex.Message)
                }
                finally
                {
                    da.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cnn.Close();
                    cnn.Dispose();
                }
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {

                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Msg.Text = "Photo setting sucessfullY";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Msg.Text = "photosetting failled";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

My ERROR
The record are not stored and image is not stored how to change in my code .

Comment: By all means ask for help, but please don't say things like *send me code* - it is considered rude.

Comment: Yes. Notice the emphasis places on the word **question** on Stack Overflow. You are _asking_ for help, not demanding it.

Comment: @Tieson T  sorry Its my mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net how to correct the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482806/asp-net-how-to-correct-the-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you're not saving the image, you're saving the path of your computer.
You need to save the byte array of the photo.

In short:
Upload its the upload control where you select the image
pic its the byte arrey where you upload the binary content of the photo 
and then you only send it as a simple parameter cmd.Parameters.Add ("@pic", pic);

```
public void OnUpload(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a byte[] from the input file

    int len = Upload.PostedFile.ContentLength; 
    byte[] pic = new byte[len];
    Upload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read (pic, 0, len);
    // Insert the image and comment into the database

    SqlConnection connection = new 
      SqlConnection (@"server=INDIA\INDIA;database=iSense;uid=sa;pwd=india");
    try
    {
        connection.Open ();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("insert into Image " 
          + "(Picture, Comment) values (@pic, @text)", connection);
         cmd.Parameters.Add ("@pic", pic);
         cmd.Parameters.Add ("@text", Comment.Text);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
     }
     finally 
     {
        connection.Close ();
     }
 }
```

here are some tutorials, the first link it's very straightforward and the code its simple
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/PicManager.aspx

another, just in case:
http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/

Principal resource: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/PicManager.aspx