# Asp.net how to correct the error

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.net how to correct the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482806/asp-net-how-to-correct-the-error)

I'm designing my web page
 My code

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } 
     public void onflbload(object sender,EventArgs e)
     {
      // Create a byte[] from the input file

     int len =flbload.PostedFile.ContentLength; 
     byte[] pic = new byte[len];
     flbload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read (pic  , 0, len);
     // Insert the image and comment into the database

     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( @"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS; 
         Initial Catalog =cat; Integrated Security=SSPI");

    try
     {
        connection.Open ();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("insert into tblphotosetting " 
        + "
(BillNo,CustomerName,Address,StartDate,EndDate,Systemurl,Numberofcopies,Amount,Total ) 
    values (@text, @text,@text,@text,@text,@pic,@text,@text,@text)", connection);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo",TextBox1.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName",TextBox2.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address",TextBox3.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate",Rdbsdate.SelectedDate);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate",Rdbddate.SelectedDate);
       cmd.Parameters.Add ("@Systemurl", pic  );
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numberofcopies",TextBox7.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount",TextBox8.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total",TextBox9.Text);


      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
     }
   finally 
   {
    connection.Close ();
   }
 }
}
```

My error image and record are not store in my database

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Dan Puzey  No Builled is sucessed page is run but image and record are not store in database

Comment: Your method `onflbload` doesn't seem to be getting called from anywhere.  Where does it get called from?

Comment: @ Dan Puzey onflbload is file upload button Id..Please change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   onflbload(sender,e)
}
```

you might want to do it like this

```
string cmdText = String.Format("insert into tblphotosetting (BillNo,CustomerName,Address,StartDate,EndDate,Systemurl,Numberofcopies,Amount,Total ) values ({0}, {1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8})",TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text,TextBox5.Text,TextBox6.Text,TextBox7.Text,TextBox8.Text,TextBox9.Text);



SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand String.Format(cmdText, connection);

cmd.CommandType= CommandType.Text ;

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

Comment: ok i used but the Error is < must declare scalre variable is '@text' >

Answer (score 0):

Could you insert code below in between try {} and finally {} ? So we can look into the problem in exception.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your insert query seems to be wrongly constructed. It should be -

```
"insert into tblphotosetting " + "
(BillNo,CustomerName,Address,StartDate,EndDate,
 Systemurl,Numberofcopies,Amount,Total ) 
    values (@BillNo, @CustomerName,@Address,@StartDate,@EndDate,
    @Systemurl,@Numberofcopies,@Amount,@Total)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't right:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo",TextBox1.Text);
```

It needs to be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = TextBox1.Text;
```

That applys for all the parameters.

Also, @Sachin is right with changing the parameters in the `CommandText` of the `SqlCommand`

Comment: @Curt The error is sqldb type is not exit

Comment: Have you includes the System.Data namespace in your web.config or page? If not, You'll need to put System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar (or add System.Data, it's neater)

Comment: @Curt  ok your command is used  but The error is sqldb type is not exit

Comment: @ Curt iam used namespace in my webpabe but ERROR isError 1 The type or namespace name 'sqldbType' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\photoshops\photoshops\photosetting.aspx.cs 14 19 photoshops

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

Comment: @Curt My error is 
           Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar