# Asp.net how to correct the error

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.net how to correct the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482806/asp-net-how-to-correct-the-error)

I'm designing my web page

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.sqldbType.Nvarchar;

    namespace photoshops
        {
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onflbload(sender, e);
    }
    public void onflbload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a byte[] from the input file

        int len = flbload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] pic = new byte[len];
        flbload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, len);
        // Insert the image and comment into the database

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS; 
                          Initial Catalog =cat; Integrated Security=SSPI");

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblphotosetting "
             + "

(BillNo,CustomerName,Address,StartDate,EndDate,Systemurl,Numberofcopies,Amount,Total ) 
 values (@BillNo,@CustomerName,@Address,@StartDate,@EndDate,@Systemurl,@Numberofcopies,@Amount,@Total)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
      TextBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
   Rdbsdate.SelectedDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =   
    Rdbddate.SelectedDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pic;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numberofcopies", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 

                            TextBox7.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text;




            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

My error is 
               image are not insert

Comment: there is no namespace that resembles System.Data.sqldbType.Nvarchar with or wothout casing. Please remove it.

Comment: @ yetanothercoder ok i remove namespace but error is Error 1 The name 'sqldbtype' does not exist in the current context

Comment: now use swaff's code. are you coding in a notepad. it seems that there is no intellisense at all?

Comment: The code has been corrected for you in the answer. Please understand that C# in a case sensitive language, so sqldbtype is meaningless, but SqlDbType is an enumeration in the System.Data namespace that you are tyring to pass into you cmd.Parameters.Add method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want SqlDbType instead of sqldbtype

[More info here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx&rct=j&q=sqldbType&ei=A2CUTfOXK4W6hAfRw_T0CA&usg=AFQjCNG3DTT6UqhTumCwQEzODKtqLCJ-XA&sig2=gcjvk5p_h6YFcMszxeID4w&cad=rja)

<strike>using System.Data.sqldbType.Nvarchar;</strike>

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =TextBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =TextBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rdbsdate.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Rdbddate.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl",SqlDbType.Image).Value= pic;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numberofcopies", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=TextBox7.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value= TextBox9.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It appears as though you are trying to save a byte[] to your table 'tblphotosetting' but the corresponding field in the table (Systemurl) is expecting an item of data of type varchar. You need to decide what you actually want to save in that field and either adjust the table schema, or the database code.

So the desire is in fact to store an image in the systemUrl field of the table 'tblphotosetting'. This field is currently a varchar so will need to be of type 'Image'. The following SQL script will make this change.

```
alter table tblphotosetting 
    alter column Systemurl image null
```

Also there has been a bit of a theme in this question answer session whereby casing has not been used correctly in this C# code, therefore I would suggest that if an IDE is not already being used, then one can download and use [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) for free.

Comment: @vimal You just need to correct the casing of your code. e.g. SqlDbType.NVarChar rather than sqldbtype.nvarchar

Comment: @ Swaff the error is Error 1 The type name 'nvarchar' does not exist in the type 'System.Data.SqlDbType'

Comment: @vimal This is the casing of the code again, see my updated example for the correct casing of the code.

Comment: @vimal: if you're struggling with how to fix the character casing in your code, I suspect you need to go back to some real fundamentals before you start playing with a database.

Comment: @Swaff Error 2 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @vimal Code updated to use Value rather than value. More casing.

Comment: @Swaff ok thankyou but error is Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.

Comment: @vimal OK, I have changed `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl",SqlDbType.NvarChar).Value= pic;` to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl",SqlDbType.Image).Value= pic;` in the example code.

Comment: @Swaff ok thank you i have changed but error is Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar

Comment: @vimal Can you post the schema of the table you are trying to write to

Comment: @Swaff ok thank you                                            BillNo numeric(18, 0) Checked
CustomerName varchar(50) Checked
Address nvarchar(50) Checked
StartDate datetime Checked
EndDate datetime Checked
Systemurl varchar(50) Checked
Numberofcopies numeric(18, 0) Checked
Amount numeric(18, 0) Checked
Total numeric(18, 0) Checked

Comment: @Swaff i have change table schema and then record are insert but image is<Binary Data> are the display is it correct?

Comment: @Swaff example       BillNo------------------                                                21 kannan river 4/4/2011 12:00:00 AM 4/6/2011 12:00:00 AM <Binary data> 2 3 23

Comment: @Swaff  I want to image location (path).how to change

Comment: @vimal What is the database you are using, SQL Server or Access?

Comment: @vimal OK, I have added an SQL alter script to the answer that will convert the SystemUrl field in the database from a varchar to the requisite Image type.

Comment: +1 for the tireless one-on-one support alone. Although I too think that looking at the OP's question history, some fundamental learning should probably take place first

Comment: @vimal [Here is a link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImageSaveInDataBase.aspx) to what your are tyring to do. I think you should start separating your individual problems over multiple questions in case they could become useful to other community members in the future. It feels as though this thread could go on forever and it is too vauge. I am a broken man....